# Create one time subscription in Laravel Cashier

Tags: laravel, strip, laravel-cashier

I built some games, and for that games, users can subscribe. I have 3 subscription methods.

- Monthly
- Yearly
- One-time.

I have used the below code.

```php
$subscription = auth()->user()->newSubscription($subscriptionName, $plan->stripe_id)->withMetaData(['game' => $game->name])->create(null, [
    'email' => $user->email,
    'name'  => $user->name,
    ['metadata' => ['game' => $game->name]],
], $subscriptionOptions);
```

But for this, I am getting the below error when I used the `one-time` subscription method. Can anyone help me out to solve this? Thanks

```
Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException
The price specified is set to `type=one_time` but this field only accepts prices with `type=recurring`.
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#single-charges
Are you looking for single charges?

Comment: Yes, Tnx. But how can we use charge with `withMetaData` and `create` like in the given example I have replaced `newSubscription` with  `charge` and passed `amount` and `method `to it., but getting `Call to undefined method Laravel\Cashier\Payment::withMetaData()` error. Can you help me?